# PHP Error-- Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, drupal

I am receiving the php error "undefined offset: 1" when the URL is domain.com/portfolio but not for domain.com/portfolio/project1. Many thanks in advance

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
$path = explode('/', $path);
if ($path[0] == 'portfolio' && $path[1] != '') {
    // action
}
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that is correct, or that worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($path[0] == 'portfolio' && !empty($path[1])) {
```

Comment: reading the docs (difference between empty and isset, which I hadn't read up before), I would have assumed that empty would still fail as the var doesn't exist as it's out of bounds of the array if there is no terminating /. Interesting though that it works. Guess my understanding of the documentation was incorrect :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($path[0] == 'portfolio') && (count($path) > 1) {
  // Do something
}
```

Or if you just want to ensure, that the index exists

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
$path = explode('/', $path);
$path = array_pad($path, 2, null);
if (($path[0] === 'portfolio') && (!is_null($path[1])) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
$path = explode('/', $path);
if ($path[0] == 'portfolio' && isset($path[1]) && $path[1] != '') {
    // action
}
```

Comment: The last two conditions are equivalent to `!empty($path[1])`.